# javax.el.CompositeELResolver class not found in Tomcat

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7

When I am developing a JSF project in Tomcat 7, the server keep arguing this class not found. May I know which jar am I missing?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.CompositeELResolver
```

I have already put this jar in the Tomcat lib folder:

1. jsf-api-2.0.1.jar
2. jsf-impl-2.0.1.jar
3. javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar

Beside this, I also have `servlet-api-2.5.jar` and `servlet-api.jar`, not sure which one is currently using by Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 container. It **already** comes along with JSP/Servlet/EL libraries by itself. You can find them all in `/lib` folder of the default (and untouched) Tomcat installation.

You should **not** add libraries of a different servletcontainer make/version in there. You should only add libraries which are not already provided by Tomcat itself. So the following statements

> - javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
>
> Beside this, I also have `servlet-api-2.5.jar` and `servlet-api.jar`,

are not a good indication that you understood it. You should remove all Servlet API libraries which you explicitly added yourself. This would only conflict with Tomcat's own ones and result in this kind of classpath troubles.

#### See also

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)